# Query to create a new field in all documents in MongoDb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add this new field to all documents in my collection using updateMany. I just cannot find the right way to do it.
My field "sits" takes an array of objects. The object is no defined in the schema. However, it currently has 3 fields: sitNumber, isAvailable, isSuspended. I can insert documents with this structure just fine. I want to add the field price : 0 to all existing documents.

This is a sample document in the collection

```
{
flightName : 65ywdbs
sits: [
{sitNumber : 1, isAvailable: true isSuspended: false} //Want to add a price field here.
]
//etc etc
}
```

My SCHEMA looks like this:

```
//models/Flight.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const flightSchema = new Schema({

    flightName :{ type : String, required :true}, 
    sits : {type : Array,
         required : true}, 
    origin : {type: String, required : true},
    destination : {type : String, required: true},
    departure : {type : Date, required : true},
    arrival : {type : Date, required : true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Flight', flightSchema)
```

This is the query that I have used to add the field price to each object in the array sits in each document of the colection:

```
//Controllers/dashboard.js

 addPrice : async(req, res) =>{
        try {
            const query =  await Flight.updateMany({}, {$set : {'sits.price':100}} )
            console.log(query)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
      
        
    }
```

This makes sense to me but it is incorrect. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using [`$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/), the all positional operator.

Your problem is similar to the example to [update all documents in an array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-all-documents-in-an-array):

> The [`$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#mongodb-update-up.---) positional operator facilitates updates to arrays that contain embedded documents. To access the fields in the embedded documents, use the [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#std-label-document-dot-notation) with the [`$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#mongodb-update-up.---) operator.
>
> ```
> db.collection.updateOne(
>   { <query selector> },
>   { <update operator>: { "array.$[].field" : value } }
> )
> ```

So in your case, your update will look like this:

```
const query = await Flight.updateMany({}, { $set : { 'sits.$[].price': 100 }})
```